# Oracle SQL: rename object attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4002.htm) for the `ALTER TYPE` statement, there seems to be no possibility to change the name, only the type. Is there any possibility to rename an attribute of an SQL object?

My first thought would be to first create an attribute with the new name, copy the data, and then drop the old attribute, but I hope there is a better solution, something like `alter type my_type rename attribute abc to xyz`.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  A type doesn't hold any data. Why would you need to copy data?

Comment: I should probably mention that I am also having a table which I create with `create table my_table of my_type`

Comment: I don't know of a better solution. Types are pain IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE [type_name]`

Comment: This won't keep the table data though, what I am looking for is a statement which renames the column but preserves the data in the dependent tables